# UITextfield not expanding in uitableviewcell

Tags: objective-c, ios

Could somebody explain how to make a UITextField within a UITableView cell expand vertically. Right now when I add text to the textfield it expands infinitely but in the horizontal direction. Is there a way to have the textfield use a fixed width and expand vertically? If there is could somebody provide sample code for this kind of functionality?

Answer (score 1):

The answer would be to use a [UITextView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UITextView_Class/), not a UITextField.

Answer (score 0):

Check this out - I created a tool that makes a uiview which holds a clickable/expandable uitextview. You can use this, set the size of the containing cell accordingly, and overwrite the functions that change height programmatically.

It's not exactly what you wanted, but it might help!
https://github.com/AlphastudioNJ/nicktitle-ui-tools/tree/master/GrowingUITextViewer